# Hibernate query syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, select, insert

This might be basic question, 
I am trying to execute insert select query using Hibernate,

```
insert into A(col1, col2) select xxx, yyy from (
    select b.col1 as xxx, c.col1 as yyy from B b,C c where someCondition1
      UNION
    select b.col1 as xxx, c.col1 as yyy from B b,C c where someCondition2
) as Z
```

Hibernate is giving

```
syntax error: Unexpected Token ( at <br/>
xxx, yyy from (...
```

While same query works when executed as SQL.

**Full stack trace is**

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 69 [Its whole query here, pasting from above question: insert into A(col1, col2) select xxx, yyy from (
    select b.col1 as xxx, c.col1 as yyy from B b,C c where someCondition1
      UNION
    select b.col1 as xxx, c.col1 as yyy from B b,C c where someCondition2
)]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1650)
    at table.handler.HibernateHandler.executeUpdate(HibernateHandler.java:404)
.
.
.
.
.
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:124)
    at com.modelling.models.ProjectDetailController$CopyProjectRunner.run(ProjectDetailController.groovy:1170)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Is something missing here?..

Comment: Post full stack trace. Where is `b.col2` in above insert?

Comment: edited the post, added stack trace.

Comment: I am not sure but are you missing `values`? i.e. `insert into table(colmns,....) values(values,....);`

Comment: @ Ankitet: I just checked documentation here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html, it says, values not needed.

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-direct

Answer (score 0):

Give Alias name to inner query.

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO A(col1, col2) 
SELECT xxx, yyy 
FROM (
    SELECT b.col1 AS xxx, c.col1 AS yyy FROM B b,C c WHERE someCondition1
      UNION
    SELECT b.col1 AS xxx, c.col1 AS yyy FROM B b,C c WHERE someCondition2
) AS A
```

**EDIT::**

```
INSERT INTO A (col1, col2) 
SELECT b.col1 AS xxx, c.col1 AS yyy FROM B b,C c WHERE someCondition1
UNION
SELECT b.col1 AS xxx, c.col1 AS yyy FROM B b,C c WHERE someCondition2
```

Comment: adding alias makes sense, tried this, still its same. I have edited the post and added alias to it.

Comment: @nIx.. Where this exists in your query:: `b.col2 from`. I am not able to locate in your query

Comment: @ Saharsh: Yeah, earlier the query was like what you suggested in edit, so values was being inserted only from first select query and second select was being ignored.